# C# WinForm static session vs instance session

Tags: c#, winforms, security, session

I have a c# winform app and I want to make it secure by implemting login and sessionfull.
So in order to do that I have two options:
1. Make the session object as static and set the values for the session's preperties after login success. (In this case the session will be accessible from any where)
2. Make one instance from the session object after login success,and just pass it around the app (in this case I need to inject the session in every class and form of the app)

Which one is more preferable and secure?

Comment: Which IoC container are you using in your application?

Comment: I use Unity, but what it have to do with the session. Or you mean injecting the session via loc.

Comment: Yep I would suggest DIing it in.